# How to get a tourist visa to the Phillipines as a freelancer?

Tags: visas, philippines, freelance

I have been working as a freelancer for a US-based company for the past year. I am going to apply for a tourist visa to the Philippines. But when I check the required documents, it is asking for an employment certificate, NOC from the employer and salary slips for the last three months. I already bought my tickets to the Philippines. I don't know what to do now. I am working as a freelancer and getting my payment through hub stuff.

My plan is to stay 20 days in the Philippines 
and a week in Singapore on my return. I already purchased my flight tickets.

Can you please help me with this? What employment document should I show on my Philippines visa interview and how to handle this situation?

Comment: perhaps writing an affidavit explaining your situation along with recent months paystubs/payments will help?

Comment: what i need to mention on affidavit and from whom i need to get the affidavit verified.does my parents need to write it Do i need to get it sign by any government organization. can you please elaborate.

Comment: What is your nationality? Speaking about "NOC" sounds like you're probably Indian, but please state so explicity in your question.